# Donkey-me crashes all the time

Tags: linux, retroarch, donkey-me

I want to play Donkey Kong in Linux. I use Manjaro xfce. I've seen that there is a game called Donkey-me on AUR which is almost the same game as Donkey Kong, but it failed to open after I installed it. As soon as I open donkey-me, it just straight away crashes. It does happen every time I open it. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: What makes you think your computer can't emulate Donkey Kong? Donkey Kong is a very old game (1981), and computers nowadays have begun emulating much more demanding machines (like the PS3).

Comment: Are you asking for game recommendations or are you asking how to resolve your issue? Its difficult to tell in the questions current state

Comment: @Nolonar, My PC has pentium P6100 with 4Gb of RAM, can we still run an emulator on it.

Comment: @Wondercricket, I'm open for anything, if you got a solution for that bring it on, I'll give any details you want. Or if you have an alternative, I'm fine with that too.

Comment: @BOSS I don’t have a solution, but I asked because recommendations are off-topic. So you should probably clarify your question :) anywho, welcome to Arqade!

Comment: @Wondercricket I just edited my question accordingly and should be a little more clear now, suggest any edits if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @BOSS, I don't see why not. I've emulated SNES, GBA, and NDS on a 2 GHz single-core Pentium 4 with only 1 GB RAM, and they're all significantly more powerful than anything Miyamoto would've had access to when he made Donkey Kong.

Comment: @Nolonar. Hmm.. then can you tell me how to play donkey kong, after you said that I think I should try emulating it, but I don't know how.

Comment: The game is available on NES, so I guess step 1 is to acquire a copy of it, step 2 is to find and install a NES emulator, and step 3 is to follow that emulator's instruction manual to get the game running.

Answer (score 1):

Donkey Me seems to be broken on both Windows and Linux in my testing, so to answer your question - No, it does not seem that you can get it working.